How to use C++ libs in C that provide the bindings?
I'm new to C. I want to use the imgui library that was written in C++ with it's base + internal + glfw + opengl3 extensions in my C project that uses glfw and opengl3 libraries. I'm aware of two projects that provide the bindings for imgui namely,

cimgui
dear-bindings

I'm running linux (debian) but I couldn't understand how to use the binding cpp files present in these binding repositories within my C project. This is the makefile of my C project,
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -std=c11 -ggdb -march=native -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fdiagnostics-show-option -I./include/
LIBS=-lm -lGL -lglfw -lGLEW
SOURCES=./src/main.c ./src/shader.c ./src/callback.c
OBJECTS={$SOURCES:.c=.o}

all: main

main: $(SOURCES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o main $(SOURCES) $(LIBS)

main.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c ./src/main.c $(LIBS)

shader.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c ./src/shader.c $(LIBS)

callback.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c ./src/callback.c $(LIBS)

clean:
    rm -f main $(OBJECTS)

Edit:  I was looking for the steps to properly call a function defined in the C++ library but from within my C project. I don't know how to use the "cpp" files (present in the binding projects above like dear-bindings and cimgui) in my C project. I'm using gcc to compile the project.

Please [edit] your question to tell us the actual problem you have with using these libraries. Do you have problem building the libraries themselves? Building the bindings? Building your application with the bindings and the libraries? Something else?

And as a possible guess, you need to build C++ source files using a C++ compiler, like g++. Once built into object files, they are like any other object file.

Usually it is the other way round(people ask for c++ way of doing things for a c lib/framework). I would recommend looking at gtk since you want c instead of c++.

I apologize @Someprogrammerdude, I was looking for the steps to properly call a function defined in the C++ library but from within my C project. I don't know how to use the "cpp" files that contain the bindings in my C code where I'm using gcc to compile the project. I'll update the question, give me a second.

"Building the bindings? Building your application with the bindings and the libraries?" I think both @Someprogrammerdude

@Ayush You call a C++ function from C in exactly the same way that you call a C function from C. I'm not sure what problem you are having.

@Ayush When you say 'call a function' do you actually mean compile the C++ code?

The C++ code needs to be designed so it can be called from C. C can't call overloaded functions because of name mangling, and it can't call class methods. The functions to be called from C need to be declared inside extern "C" { ... } blocks.

"hen you say 'call a function' do you actually mean compile the C++ code?" @john yeah!  the only way to compile the c++ code is to use g++. gcc can't compile cpp sources so i don't know why the bindings are present in cpp files. shouldn't there be a c source and a header only in the bindings of these libraries that i can simply put in ./include and call it a day?

I see! @Barmar. Suppose I have a "bindings.h" that declare the extern "C" {...} functions. I also have a binding.cpp that contains the implementation of those functions. The problem is I'm using gcc which can't compile cpp souces and therefore I don't know how to include the implementation of these function declarations in my C project without porting over to g++.

@Ayush You seem to have a misunderstanding about g++. Both g++ and gcc are capable of compiling C++ code (or C code). Both programs compile C or C++ depending on the file extension. The only difference between the two is the instructions they pass onto the linker with regard to incorporating standard libraries. I don't know enough about your situation to know if g++ or gcc is necessary. My instinct would be to switch everything to g++ (including the C code) but that's only my guess. No porting of code will be necessary.

@Ayush If you really want to stick to gcc, then try gcc for everything, if will compile the C++ code. The only possible errors I would expect are linker errors. So if you see linker errors that seem to be refering to C++ items, then you probably need g++.

Hey @john! I figured it out. Thank you so much for helping. I compiled c files with gcc and cpp files with g++. I then linked alll the object files to my ./main binary using g++. The only reason I'm using gcc to compile c files is because I'm using immediate assignments as arguments to some functions for example do_something((float[3]){1.0f,2.0f,3.0f}) which throws an error in g++ as immediate assignments are discouraged.  It was a mess but the libraries I wanted to use are working now within my C project. : D
